# Episode of a show where a guy and a girl search for a mermaid

Tags: story-identification, tv, mermaids

I’m trying to remember this episode of this show I watched when I was younger. It was this show of this guy and girl. I wanna say it was a reality show, maybe.

In this episode they are looking for a mermaid. It was this video of this mermaid swimming away. They were trying to look for her. The guy and the girl of the show put a tail on or maybe they just free dived. They got in the water. It was like a little skit! They had this woman dressed as a mermaid, but they were like “we saw one but she wasn’t the one we were looking for”.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Scifi.SE! When exactly did you watch this?

Comment: So there was no real mermaid in the show? It was just a woman wearing a tail costume?

Comment: Reading the post reminded of of this Dark Angel episode though: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0554575/